# Postgresql search for items older than a threshold

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Seems like this should be a simple thing to do, but the date/time operations in postgresql are killing me.  All I'm looking to do is search for items older than 10 minutes.  Coding language is PHP.

Field `event_time` is: timestamp without time zone NOT NULL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE 
        event_time < ( now() - interval '-{$threshold} minutes' )
        AND submitted=0 ";
```

This query is returning all results instead of items older than 10 minutes.  Do I need to type cast that event_time field somehow?

Comment: Can you show us what the real statement is? What's that busines with the dash before the threshold value? In plain SQL it should be `now() - interval '10' minute` or `now - interval '10 minutes'` (note: no dash before the `10`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a negative threshold value, you have a double negative, so you are searching for everything less than ten minutes in the future (which would naturally return everything). Just use `interval '{$threshold} minutes}'`

Comment: another alternative is: `event_time - now() > interval '10' minute` (I personally find that more readable)

Comment: Yep, that appears to be it. I am a moron.  Thank you sir! ;)

Comment: @MichaelGuthrie If this solved your problem, you should accept this answer, as it will build your reputation and make people more willing to answer questions you have in the future.